# How to replace Fancybox with Colorbox in Prestashop 1.5.3?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, prestashop, colorbox

How to replace Fancybox with Colorbox in Prestashop 1.5.3.1? I found 24 files that have references to Fancybox.

[files](http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/9791/prestashop.png)

Comment: to replace fancy box with color box, then you have to first decide where you want to use it. Lets consider you want to use it at product pages, then include the js and css files for colorbox there, and add the needed html etc for color box. Also note that you have to remove the fancy box from those pages.

Comment: I want to replace Fancybox completely, for a start point I want to replace it on product pages, and when add to shopping cart. How to properly place Colorbox plugin directory inside Prestashop plugins directory?